# How to use slice after condition in Twig's "FOR"

Tags: twig

Problem is with slicing `main_collection`, it slicing all elements before `if` condition is executed, therefore i can't limit number of outputted elements to 1, because `main_collection` could have 50-1000 items, so it's slicing within these 1000 items which resulting to no results, i want to apply slicing only after `if p.header.main_article` condition.

```
{% for p in main_collection|slice(0, 1) if p.header.main_article %}  
    <article class="main-news">
        <a href="{{ p.url }}">
            <h4>{{ p.title }}</h4>
        </a>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: So.. What are u trying to do here? You are trying to only items the are a `main_article`? Just omit the `slice` filter then

Comment: Trying to display 1 item, that has `main_article` set to true, instead of 1000 items with/without `main_article` set to true.

Comment: Don't try do this in pure `twig`. Are u able to extend `twig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in pure `twig`, which I wouldn't consider as `twig` can't breakout of loops you would need to use something like the following

```
{% set item = null %}
{% set item_found = false %}

{% for p in main_collection %}
    {% if p.header.main_article and not item_found %}{% set item = p %}{% set item_found = true %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<article class="main-news">
    <a href="{{ item.url }}">
        <h4>{{ item.title }}</h4>
    </a>
</article>
```

---

It would be better to extend twig and create an extra filter like this

```
    $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('first_main_article', $main_collection) {
        foreach($main_collection as $p) if ($p->getHeader()->getMainArticle()) return $p;
        return null;
    }
```

Then use it inside `twig`

```
{% set item = main_collection | first_main_article %}
{% if item %}
    <article class="main-news">
        <a href="{{ item.url }}">
            <h4>{{ item.title }}</h4>
        </a>
    </article>
{% endif %}
```

---

If you want more than one item you should use an array and adjust like the code like this

```
{% set items = [] %}
{% for p in main_collection %}
    {% if items|length < 3 and p.header.main_article %}
        {% set items = items|merge([p]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in items %}
    <article class="main-news">
        <a href="{{ item.url }}">
            <h4>{{ item.title }}</h4>
        </a>
    </article>      
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Will try this out now, without writing an extension

Comment: This worked, thanks! Can you extend a bit your answer on how to display 2 images for example?

Comment: @AlexanderKim extended answer

Comment: ty, i can't understand the part with settings `item` and `item_found` - could you explain it?

Comment: As you can't break a for loop in `twig` it's necesary to keep track wether u have found an item that meets your requirment. If u wouldn't add this flag, then the last item with the flag active would be stored in the variable `item` instead of the first one

Comment: Thanks again, but what with ordering items? For example, if i have descending order set 3, 2, 1 how it will be displayed in case of single item?

Comment: Ordering and modifying is not realy suited to be done inside `twig`, i'd suggest to use `php` for this